# Meteor - Loading scripts in footer

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor

Is it possible to configure Meteor to load the JavaScript in the footer of the body? At the moment it is slowing down the loading of my hero image to the point where it really impacts the user experience.

To clarify, I have added this package;

```
https://github.com/d0minikk/materialize-meteor
```

I would like for the DOM load order to end up like this in production;

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="i am the bare minimum needed by meteor">
    <link rel="materialize.css">
    meta
    ..
</head>
<body>
    <img src="my hero image">
    ..
    <script src="everything else needed by meteor">
    <script src="materialize.js">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as in, the route-specific javascript loads, and then the external js is loaded?  do you need the those js files on the hero image page?

Answer (score 0):

When you add in a package it automatically decides the load order in the best way to use dependencies correctly and have the fastest load order.

I think your question has another answer but not directly relating to what you ask.

1) Meteor automatically references the files so there is no need to put in the script tags yourself

2) In deployment mode, everything is concatenated and optimised for debugging. It will be a bit slow.

But in deployment mode, when you build your app with `meteor deploy`, `meteor build`, or run it with `meteor --production` it will behave a bit differently. All your js will be just one single file and you will have only 1 js file referenced containing a minified version of all the other files such as the `materialize.js` file.

Essentially there is no need to try and optimise loading order as Meteor will do this for you and go the step further of minifying and concatenating your files when in production. When you're deploying it it keeps it this slow way to help you debug it better.

Comment: That's my main problem. Google page analyzer is flagging the JS as containing "render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content". Am I losing control over this performance fine tuning by choosing Meteor?

Comment: @BrianF this is the essential design of a Meteor app. The index.html is actually empty and the js loads it up. Google page analyser does not know this (try wget your localhost:3000 page) and expects some content. I guess this is why it flags it as render blocking, but you should account it when using Meteor. There are benefits and caveats to using Meteor but on overall you get very nice speed improvements after the initial load (which is very CDNable & cacheable since the js files are static)

Comment: Thanks @Akshat. Coming from SPA's I understand what Meteor is doing, I'd just like to fine tune it a little bit and tell it what's not essential on landing and let it split that out to a separate file. Maybe I'll have to dig in to the mechanics of it.